# JDO 1:N issue (retriving data)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have class to work on PDF

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class GoogleDrivePDF {

        @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        private Key key;

        @Persistent
        private String pdfName;

       ... geter, seter...

}
```

In order to write and read data, I do like this:

```
GoogleDrivePDF pdf = new GoogleDrivePDF();
 key=KeyFactory.createKey(GoogleDrivePDF.class.getSimpleName(),"0B1IQEoiXFg3IWHhJNEtlMzlvQWs");
 pdf.setKey(key);           
 pdf.setPdfName("NAME");
 pm.makePersistent(pdf);
```

and in order to read:

```
 pdf  = pm.getObjectById(GoogleDrivePDF.class,  "0B1IQEoiXFg3IWHhJNEtlMzlvQWs1");
```

**Everything works!**

Now I  will create **One: Many** realationship.

```
    @PersistenceCapable
    public class UsersPDFDocuments {

        @PrimaryKey
        @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
        private Key key;

        @Persistent
        private List<GoogleDrivePDF> pdfs;

        ... seter, geter...
}
```

and I write to Database:

```
         List <GoogleDrivePDF> pdfFilesDao=...
         GoogleDrivePDF pdf = new GoogleDrivePDF();
         Key key= KeyFactory.createKey(GoogleDrivePDF.class.getSimpleName(), "0B1IQEoiXFg3IWHhJNEtlMzlvQWs1");
         pdf.setKey(key);
         pdf.setVerifyed(false);
         pdf.setPdfName("mari123");
         pdfFilesDao.add(pdf);  

         key= KeyFactory.createKey(UsersPDFDocuments.class.getSimpleName(), "mail@mail");
         UsersPDFDocuments userData = new UsersPDFDocuments();
         userData.setKey(key);
         userData.setPdfs(pdfFilesDao);

         pm.makePersistent(userData);
```

**OK everything works!** **BUT I CAN NOT READ PDF DATA NOW!**

I have error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /test. Reason:


     Could not retrieve entity of kind GoogleDrivePDF with key GoogleDrivePDF("0B1IQEoiXFg3IWHhJNEtlMzlvQWs1")
    Caused by:

    javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException: Could not retrieve entity of kind GoogleDrivePDF with key GoogleDrivePDF("0B1IQEoiXFg3IWHhJNEtlMzlvQWs1")
```

**BUT I DO THE SAME , LIKE I WAS DOING:**

```
 Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(GoogleDrivePDF.class.getSimpleName(), "0B1IQEoiXFg3IWHhJNEtlMzlvQWs1");
         GoogleDrivePDF pdf = pm.getObjectById(GoogleDrivePDF.class,    key);
```

[image]

When I was testing, In order to get the value, I need  enycrypted String of key. (See image)  `agtsdHYtY2hlY2tlcnJoCxIRVXNlcnNQREZEb2N1bWVudHMiIXZha2h0YW5nLmtvcm9naGxpc2h2aWxpQGdtYWlsLmNvbQwLEg5Hb29nbGVEcml2ZVBERiIcMEIxSVFFb2lYRmczSVdIaEpORXRsTXpsdlFXcww`

when I add Unowned  it works! why?!

```
@Unowned
    @Persistent
    private List<GoogleDrivePDF> pdfs;
```

Comment: if I add @Unowned , it works. why?

Comment: Strongly suggest you at least read the GAE docs about "owned" relations and the effect that has on the Key of an object. Should be a prerequisite to using it